# Prolog beginner, member/2 builtin predicate

Tags: prolog

I have this:

```
someuserdef(a,[b,c,d]).
```

When I try

```
?- someuserdef(a,L),member(b,L).
```

I don't get a true or false answer but the list

```
L=[b,c,d] ;
false.
```

How do I get just a true or false answer?

Comment: P.S. Note that `member/2` may or may not be a **built-in** predicate. In some Prolog systems, is instead a **library** predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking Prolog to give you a value of `L` that matches both rules.  If it can tell that there's only one answer, it will return `yes` - otherwise it will give you the first answer, return `no`, and prompt you before checking for any more answers.

When you're providing *variables* (capital letters) to Prolog queries, it will return matches - it's when you ask it to check rules (with no variables) e.g. `someuserdef(b, [b, c, d])` that it will return `yes` or `no` to indicate whether your assertion is true or false.